# Column sum mismatching while taking sum

Tags: python, pandas

My df is below

```
   Cost,Reve,diff
    0,3
    4,0
    0,0
    10,10
    4,8
    -3,0
```

My formula is `df['diff'] = df['Cost'] - df['Reve']`

When i took the sum it shows the difference

```
df['diff'].sum() = 50

df['Cost'].sum() = 200

df['Reve'].sum() = 100
```

My analysis

When i debugged(saved into csv and checked) where Cost is `negative or positve` and Rev is `0` then diff is becoming zero. Like in 7th  and second row Cost is `-3` and Reve is `0` the expected diff is zero but I am getting null values

Comment: I think maybe `Reve` isn't 0 but actually empty and you cannot do the subtraction in which case you could solve it using pd.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: @Nathan df.fillna(0,inplace=True), i done before

Comment: It works fine for me too, are you sure you work on the above dataframe?

Comment: You're saying that you saved that into a csv, loaded it back in and can reproduce it in a fresh interactive terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed as guided by @Nathan

```
df[['Cost', 'Reve']] = df[['Cost', 'Reve']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```